# Loop inside loop

Tags: php, math, loops

I have this difficult task (for me at least).
This is abstract question, mathematical i'd say.
Let's assume I have 2 inputs:

1. a keyword (string)
2. a number (deepness level)

and submit button.

This keyword returns me 8 other keywords from a database that are similar to this string.
And for each of that 8 keywords I need to call same function that will return me another 8 similar keywords of all these 8 strings I have already returned.
Here comes the "level" number. I need to go deeper inside every of returned string depending on level number I entered.

For example: If the level number is 2, then we will call the function 9 times. First time for the original keyword, and 8 times for each returned keyword.
If the level number is 3, then the function will be called 73 times. Like in the previous example, but plus for another 8 keywords we have returned. I think there will be a couple of loops inside loops, but can't figure it out by myself. Will appreciate your suggestions.

Here's the main code that I have wrote which is probably unsufficient:

```
$keywords = preg_split('/$\R?^/m', trim($_POST['keyword']));
$keywords = array_map('trim', $keywords);
$level = $_POST['level'];
if (!$level || $level < 2) {
    echo '<b>Level was either 1 or null</b>';
}
foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
    $results = getResults($keyword);
    if ($level && $results) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($results); $i++) {
            $results1 = getResults($results[$i]);
            for ($j = 0; $j < $level; $j++) {
                $results1 = getResults($results1[$i])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output should be something like this:

```
1->
   2
   ->
      3
      3
      3
      3
      3
      3
      3
      3
   2->
   2->
   2->
   2->
```

Comment: Here's the main code that I have wrote which is probably unsufficient:

Comment: Wouldn't level 3 give you 1 + 8 + 64 function calls?

Comment: Sounds like simple recursion to me.

Comment: Can you add sample with expected output ?

Comment: It should be like a multidimensional array i think.
If I have entered 3 keywords and the level is 1 then I should get:
1+8; if level is 2 then 1+8+64, if 3 then 1+8+64+4096

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to understand what `recursion` [means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) and how you can use it in your code. Basically you need to call the same function inside itself, n times where n is the deepness level of your request.

Start with some little examples like Fibonacci series, and you will find the way to implement your function.

All is based on a condition `($deepness > 0)`.

Here's a little suggestion (in pseudocode) based on what I understood.

```
function findSimilar($words,$deepness) {
    if($deepness == 0) {
        return similarWordsOf($words);
    } else {
        return similarWordsOf(findSimilar($words,$deepness -1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't this just give one long list of transitively similar words?

Comment: It's just a draft function. Will you give him a full solution?

Answer (score 0):

As others have already pointed out, the key to the solution is to use a recursive function, i.e. a function that calls itself again for each of the similar words using a decreased deepness value.

My PHP is a bit rusty, so here's some pseudo code (aka Python):

```
def printSimilar(word, deepness=1, indent=0):
    print ("  " * indent) + word
    if deepness > 0:
        for similar in similarWords(word):
            printSimilar(similar, deepness - 1, indent + 1)
```

Assuming that `similarWords` returns the list of similar words, this should result in the desired output.